# Which HTML tags have no content

Tags: html, xhtml

Some HTML tags like br and hr have no content and cannot have a closing tag.  What is the complete set of these tags?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check the table at http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/elements.html.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the 'EMPTY' column here:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/elements.html

Comment: @JohnB What does that mean? It *is* in the link given.

Answer (score 0):

Every tag in the [DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/sgml/dtd.html) that has `EMPTY` in the fourth field is empty.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/default.asp

All the one that has a forward slash in their tag name. (correction) thx =O

Comment: Forward slash. \ is backslash.

Comment: Cannot be seen in this list anymore.

Answer (score -1):

Html don't force the document to be well formatted, so end tags for certain tags like `<br>` and `<hr>` can be left out and still the page loads fine, but it's like they cannot have end tags `</br>` and `<br />` works just fine. There is probably no division like Content and Non-Content tags, Refer to this article for details on Tags http://www.devx.com/projectcool/Article/19816

Comment: HTML has a defined syntax, it isn't the language's fault that a number of popular parsers for it have excellent error handling features. "There is probably no division like Content and Non-Content tags" — there is, it is clearly defined in the specification. As for that article, it appears to have no content aside from a demand that I register.