# Check - can node have children?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Is there a portable way to check if some element can accept and show childNodes, except checking tagName `switch(node.tagName)` or alike? I need to implement some kind of d&d and I'd like to insert moved node in the nearest to `document.elementFromPoint` position (where dragged node has been dropped). But, as I understand, it's meaningless to insert an element in the `<img>`, for example, so I'll need to `insertBefore` this img's parentNode in that case.
Of course, it is possible to check against tags list, but maybe there's more portable and simple solution?

Thank you

Comment: what's wrong with checking against a list of tags?

Comment: Who said that it's wrong? This list just will be a bit large and can be changed in the future, so maybe there is a simpler way to do that? Just look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element - it's not so small, isn't it? ))

Comment: You need to know more than "can have children" anyway, since there are many elements that can only be children of specific other elements, e.g. TD must be a child of TR and LI must be a child of UL or OL. Similarly, some elements can only have specific child nodes, e.g. TR can only have TD children, and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, I don't think there's a builtin function to check whether a certain tag is [a void one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25313426/1048572). It's a pretty arbitrary decision of HTML, there's no DOM attribute for it. (In XML documents, every element can theoretically have children).

So checking against the official list is indeed the way to go. For HTML4, see [Which HTML tags have no content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3581066/1048572), for HTML5 see the [list of *void elements* in the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/syntax.html#void-elements):

```
area, base, br, col, embed, hr, img, input, keygen, link, menuitem, meta, param, source, track, wbr
```

Comment: Well, it's not exactly what I'm lloking for, but close. In my case it's also meaningless to insert into lists or selects etc. Ok, maybe it's really depends on purpose and approach. Thank you, gone writing switch-case list then ))))

Comment: @BbIKTOP You can inserts `<li>`s in lists and `<option>`s in selects. If you want to insert a particular element, say a `<div>`, then of course it's not semantically valid in certain contexts. See the different [content models](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/dom.html#content-model) for that.

Comment: Of course, but it’s useless to insert anything else than li in the list, that ’s what I meant. I have to make my own list for this particular case then

Comment: Again, don't make your own but use the [official list](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/fullindex.html#index-elements) :-)

Comment: As I said, there’s no list for my task ) but at least now I understand it ))

Comment: As I said in the question, i'm implementing some kind of d&d and need to insert "dropped" element at the drop place. Well, I've got enough info to realize what I really need, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You may use method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22046336/2046306) (The question and answer are not mine). It answers different question but may still be helpful. 
I'm pasting here the accepted answer, although there are also other answers in this question, may be useful to you.
This is a check whether the element can contain text

```
function canElementContainText(tagname) {
    try {
        var e = document.createElement(tagname);
        return e.outerHTML.indexOf("/") != -1;
    } catch (ex) {
       return false;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var result = canElementContainText(myElement.tagName);
```